# Gazebo client uses 100% cpu when closed

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I close the gazebo gui interface, gzclient takes the cpu usage goes to 100% and never finish.

I am using osrf-gazebo-0430b632cdc0, with CEGUI 0.7.8 and OGRE 1.8.1.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1034/gazebo-client-uses-100%-cpu-when-closed/) by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 305 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is fixed in the latest gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on 2015-04-08**:
This is still happening to me in Gazebo 4.1.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-04-09**:
We haven't experienced this problem in almost 2 years. Can you provide more information? Are you using any plugins, what world are you loading, what is your machine?